# wicket ModalWindow error

Tags: java, wicket

I'm new to wicket, and I get he following error when I try to run my application:

WicketMessage: Modal window content id is wrong. Component ID:myPanel; content ID: content:

in my AddStudent html:

```
<span wicket:id="InformationDialog"/>
<span wicket:id="myPanel"/>
```

These are the first things after my opening  tag

in AddStudent.java(in the constructor):

```
panel=new InformationPanel("myPanel");
message=new ModalWindow("InformationDialog");
message.setContent(panel);
message.setCssClassName(ModalWindow.CSS_CLASS_BLUE);
message.setTitle("Important Information");
```

where InformationPanel extends Panel:

```
<html>
<wicket:panel>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span wicket:id="message"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type ="button" value ="OK" wicket:id="ok"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</wicket:panel>
<html>
```

Obviously, I have a corresponding java class-it might not be relevant but here it is:

```
package myapp.project;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Button;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;

public class InformationPanel extends Panel {
    private Button ok;
    private Label messageLabel;
    public InformationPanel(String id){
        super(id);
        messageLabel=new Label("message","");
        ok=new Button("ok"){
            public void onSubmit(){
                AddStudent student = new AddStudent();
                setResponsePage(student);
            }
        };
        add(ok);
        add(messageLabel);

    }
    public void setSuccessful(){
        messageLabel.setDefaultModelObject("You have successfully added the student");
    }
    public void setUnSuccessful(){
        messageLabel.setDefaultModelObject("A student with that username already exists!");
    }

}
```

No idea of the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your AddStudent.java constructor , you have

```
panel=new InformationPanel("myPanel");
message=new ModalWindow("InformationDialog");
message.setContent(panel);
```

Wicket `ModalWindow` needs its content to have a specific id, which you're not matching.

Try changing this to

```
message=new ModalWindow("InformationDialog");
panel=new InformationPanel(message.getContentId());
message.setContent(panel);
```

The `message.getContentId()` should make the ids align.

Comment: Thank you, but now it says:WicketMessage: Unable to find component with id 'InformationDialog' in [MarkupContainer [Component id = _extend8]]. This means that you declared wicket:id=InformationDialog in your markup, but that you either did not add the component to your page at all, or that the hierarchy does not match.
[markup = file:/C:/workspace/MyApp/context/WEB-INF/classes/myapp/project/AddStudent.html

Comment: That's a mismatch between your html markup and your java.  Is your AddStudent class missing an `add(message)`?

Comment: Thats right -realised this very soon after I posted-thought I posted that I'd sorted it, but obviously not. Thank you so much!